# Searching for the active record without the last

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I get the names of sellers that have a certain goal? Follow the model below:

[image]

How can I get the names of sellers that have a certain goal? I have the right database model.

I'm trying like this:

```
GoalSalesman.where (goal_id: 1).last.salesman.name
```

But so I get only the last name because of `last`, I wanted all the names.

How can I get all of the names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting up the associations as:

```
GoalSalesman.rb
  belongs_to :goal
  belongs_to :salesman

Goal.rb
  has_many :goal_salesmen
  has_many :salesmen, through: :goal_salesmen

Salesman.rb
  has_many :goal_salesmen
  has_many :goals, through: :goal_salesmen
```

You should then be able to get all the names by calling

```
Goal.find(1).salesmen.pluck(:name)
```